# Separability of Banach space.

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $B(X, Y)$ be the Banach space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.

I want to know the conditions under which imply that $B(X, Y)$ is separable? Please help.

Comment: In the case of Hilbert spaces $B(X,Y)$ is separable iff $X$ is finite dimensional and $Y$ is separable or $Y$ is finite dimensional and $X$ is separable.

Comment: As Robert Israel pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3495274/495075) there exist infinite-dimensional separable Banach spaces $X,Y$ such that $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ **is** norm-separable. Generally speaking---at least this is the feeling I have---the situation for arbitrary Banach spaces seems to be very messy.